# Can't fetch firebase dynamic link in swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have set up dynamic links for my firebase project each post has a dynamic link. I can copy the link into Safari and it shows me the title and all the right info I can then open the app from the link but for some reason, I can't present a certain controller when the link is clicked and I can't print anything out from the function below. Having serious trouble receiving the link.

**ViewController - Creating (Works well!)**

```
var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = "https"
        components.host = "www.example.com.au"
        components.path = "/posts"

        let postIdQueryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "postId", value: post.postId)
        components.queryItems = [postIdQueryItem]

        guard let linkParam = components.url else { return }

        guard let shareLink = DynamicLinkComponents(link: linkParam, domainURIPrefix: "https://example.page.link") else { return }
        let options = DynamicLinkComponentsOptions()

        options.pathLength = .short

        guard let bundleId = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier else { return }
        shareLink.options = options
        shareLink.iOSParameters = DynamicLinkIOSParameters(bundleID: bundleId)

        shareLink.iOSParameters?.appStoreID = "1456561852"
        shareLink.socialMetaTagParameters = DynamicLinkSocialMetaTagParameters()
        shareLink.socialMetaTagParameters?.title = "\(post.title)."
        shareLink.socialMetaTagParameters?.descriptionText = post.details

        guard let longUrl = shareLink.url else { return }
        shareLink.shorten { (url, warning, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

            guard let shortUrl = url else { return }
            print(shortUrl)
            self.showShareSheet(url: shortUrl)
        }
```

**AppDelegate - Receiving**

```
    func handleIncomingDynamicLink(_ dynamicLink: DynamicLink) {
    guard let url = dynamicLink.url else { return }
    print("Incoming link is \(url.absoluteString)")

    guard let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else { return }
    guard let queryItems = components.queryItems else { return }

    if components.path == "/posts" {
        //Load a specific event
        if let postIdQueryItem = queryItems.first(where: {$0.name == "postId"}) {
            guard let postId = postIdQueryItem.value else { return }
            let homeController = HomeController()
            homeController.presentAlert()
        }
    }
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, contuine userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    if let incomingUrl = userActivity.webpageURL {
        print("Incoming URL is \(incomingUrl)")
        let linkHandled = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().handleUniversalLink(incomingUrl) { (dynamicLink, error) in

            if let error = error {
                return
            }

            if let dynamicLink = dynamicLink {
                self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
            }
        }
        return linkHandled
    }
    return false
}


func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if let dynamicLink = DynamicLinks.dynamicLinks().dynamicLink(fromCustomSchemeURL: url) {
        self.handleIncomingDynamicLink(dynamicLink)
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: It probably means that `url` object is nil in the dynamic link, if it's only happening in iOS 13, this issue might be helpful: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/3918

Comment: Also, make sure you're updating Firebase pods to the latest release